# How to replace parent element of iframe without its reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

Here is the situation.

```
<div id="a1" class="aa" onclick="func1();">
<iframe id="iframe1" src="www.google.com" />
</div>

<div id="a2" class"bb" onclick="func2();">
</div>
```

I would like to replace a1 with a2 without iframe1 reloading.
But moving iframe1 such as **a2.appendChild(iframe1);** triggers iframe reloading.

So I guess the only way is replace a1's property such as

**for(attr in a2.attributes){ a1.setAttribute(attr, a2.attributes.attr ); }**

But it does not work. It could prevent iframe reloading, but a1, a2 nodes not work properly.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: as a side note, the correct syntax is `<iframe></iframe>`

Comment: It's because the method "appendChild" insert a new content as a child. So the iFrame is loaded. Try with appendTo perhaps...

Comment: _“but a1, a2 nodes not work properly”_ – please describe _that_ problem _appropriately_.